# How to check if a certificate is self signed in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, self-signed, x509certificate2

I'm writing code that is supposed to alert the user if he tries to access a web address with a self signed certificate.
I'm using the following code:

```
  private static bool ServerCertificateValidationCallback(object sender, X509Certificate 
              certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {

        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        {

            log.Info("Certificate OK ");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            log.Info("Certificate ERROR ");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Using this code I know when the certificates verification fails, but I'm not sure how to find the specific condition in which the certificate is self signed. I looked for other answers and found that if the issuer and the subject are the same then there are good chances it is a self signed certificate but that's not 100% certain. My question is, is there any logic or condition which will tell me with certainty whether it's a self signed certificate or not, or is such a check already exist as part of .NET?

Comment: Check the `X509Certificate2.Issuer` and `X509Certificate2.Subject` (or `X509Certificate2.IssuerName` and `X509Certificate2.SubjectName`) properties. If these are the same...

Answer (score 0):

If none of the values on `chain.ChainStatus` are `PartialChain` or `NotValidSignature` and `chain.ChainElements.Length` is 1, it’s self-signed.